# HighCharts: Logarithmic scale

Tags: highcharts

I am using **logarithmic axes** on HighCharts and sometimes the chart will not render due to issues such as negative or 0 values which is totally understandable but it also fails if the axis label happens to be 0 or less as well. My question is: is there a way to capture or detect this issue during rendering so that I can dynamically change to linear axes as a fallback and render a message to notify the user why it failed?

Here is an example of a failed curve rendering due to a 0 label on the x-axis:

http://jsfiddle.net/axl163/Eqc5G/1/

Here are some more details on the HighCharts error:

http://www.highcharts.com/errors/10

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your series add pointStart:1 and it should work. example:

```
    series: [{            
        data: [0.001,1,1.2,1.4, 2,30],
        pointStart: 1
    }]
```

Comment: I agree, the problem is that Highcharts starts incrementation from 0 for xAxis, so when setting `xAxis: { type: 'logarithmic' }` required is to or set pointStart, or use arrays of [x,y] pairs instead of just y-values in data.

Answer (score 1):

I addressed this issue by checking the values that go into HighCharts and if there are unacceptable values, the axes will automatically be changed to linear.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem setting the pointStart and min attribute of yAxis.
Here an example:

```
yAxis: {
    min: 1
},
series: [{            
    data: [0.001,1,1.2,1.4, 2,30],
    pointStart: 1
}]
```